# zsh: killed git on Mac

Tags: terminal, mac, homebrew, git, apple-silicon

Hi~ I am just using a Mac with M1 chip.

I just found when I tried to run

```
git clone ...
```

I got

```
zsh: killed git
```

What should I do?

I have tried to reinstall `git` via `brew`.
but it doesn't work.

git version:

```
git-2.30.1.arm64_big_sur.bottle.tar.gz
```

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :) As for your question, how did you try to reinstall `git`? By using `brew reinstall git`? (Note: that's **re**install and not just install). Also, when you say you tried reinstalling it and "it doesn't work", what actually happens?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you used the `brew reinstall git` command instead of `brew install git`, and assuming you still have Command Line Tools installed, then I would first install `gettext` and `pcre2` as git needs them.

So, first do...

```
brew reinstall gettext
```

...followed by:

```
brew reinstall pcre2
```

and then by...

```
brew reinstall git
```

If that doesn't work you could try all the commands again but with `install` instead of `reinstall`.

And if that doesn't work, what's the result of `brew config`?

Answer (score 1):

I have an M1 so I had to install `xcode-select` first because reinstalling `gettext` or `pcre2` was not running either.

Do it in this order:

```
xcode-select --install
brew reinstall gettext
brew reinstall pcre2
brew reinstall git
```

Good Luck!